# JavaScript doesn't change divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem with JS. I want JS to change the class of some div with AJAX. Works fine until it should find the divs.

```js
    function filter(cb){
  var value = cb.value;
  if(cb.checked){ var state = "an" }
  if(!cb.checked){ var state = "aus" }
  var pstring = "Checkbox "+value+" = "+state;
  var url  = "shownitems.php?checkbox="+value;
  $.get(url,
   {
   },
   function(data){
    var array = JSON.parse(data)

    if(cb.checked){
     array.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
                        //alert(value) works fine for every index
      var divstring = value+"cont";
                        //alert(divstring) gives correct id. div "1cont" exists!
      var div = document.getElementById(divstring);
      alert(div); //null
     });
    }
    if(!cb.checked){
     array.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
      var divstring = value+"cont";
      var div = document.getElementById(divstring);
      alert(div);
     });
    }
      
   }
  ); 
 }
```

What can I do?

Comment: Get rid of your single quotes for the div member.

Comment: Nice try, didn't work ...

Comment: When I use your code, I get a `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ''`

Comment: `var div = "'#"+value+"cont'";` shouldn't have any single quotes in it. they're not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove single quotes, because your selector will look like `"'#foo'"`

```
var div = "#" + value + "cont";
```

Comment: I would suggest debugging that script a little, you need to make sure that $(div) doesn't return an empty array.

Comment: document.getElementByID() gives null! See the new Snippet ;)

Comment: If you're using document.getElementById(), then you don't need the "#" character at the beginning of your selector string.

That function returns null, when you're trying to get an element, which is not present in your current DOM.

So the options are the same: either your HTLM elements have different ids, either you're using a wrong selector.

Comment: Got that already. Thank you, works fine now! Now, let's just script a lighbox and a zip generator ... -.-

Comment: I am happy to help! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the stub I set up for adding and removing classes as it pertains to your question:

```js
function tryFunc1(value) {
  /**
   * @throws Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ''
   */
  var div = "'#" + value + "cont'";
  $(div).removeClass('imgthumbbox');
  $(div).addClass('hidden');
  console.log($(div));
}


function tryFunc2(value) {
  /**
   * @returns {array}
   */
  var div = "#" + value + "cont";
  $(div).removeClass('imgthumbbox');
  $(div).addClass('hidden');
  console.log($(div));
}


tryFunc2('colecmc');

tryFunc1('colecmc');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colecmc" class="imgthumbbox">Hello</div>
```